# Retrieved Dictionary Key Not Found

Tags: c#, dictionary, readonly-collection

I have a `SortedDictionary` declared like such:

```
SortedDictionary<MyObject,IMyInterface> dict = new SortedDictionary<MyObject,IMyInterface>();
```

When its populated with values, if I grab any key from the dictionary and then try to reference it immediately after, I get a `KeyNotFoundException`:

```
MyObject myObj = dict.Keys.First();
var value = dict[myObj];     // This line throws a KeyNotFoundException
```

As I hover over the dictionary (after the error) with the debugger, I can clearly see the same key that I tried to reference is in fact contained in the dictionary.  I'm populating the dictionary using a `ReadOnlyCollection` of `MyObjects`.  Perhaps something odd is happening there?  I tried overriding the `==` operator and `Equals` methods to get the explicit comparison I wanted, but no such luck.  That really shouldn't matter since I'm actually getting a key directly from the `Dictionary` then querying the `Dictionary` using that same key.  I can't figure out what's causing this.  Has anyone ever seen this behavior?

**EDIT 1**

In overriding `Equals` I also overloaded (as MS recommends) `GetHashCode` as well.  Here's the implementation of `MyObject` for anyone interested:

```
public class MyObject
{
public string UserName { get; set;}
public UInt64 UserID  { get; set;}

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null || GetType()!= obj.GetType())
        {
            return false;
        }

        // Return true if the fields match:
        return this.Equals((MyObject)obj);
    }

    public bool Equals(MyObject other)
    {
        // Return true if the fields match
        return this.UserID == other.UserID;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return (int)this.UserID;
    }


public static bool operator ==( MyObject a, MyObject b)
{
    // If both are null, or both are same instance, return true.
    if (System.Object.ReferenceEquals(a, b))
    {
        return true;
    }

    // If one is null, but not both, return false.
    if (((object)a == null) || ((object)b == null))
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Return true if the fields match:
    return a.UserID == b.UserID
}

public static bool operator !=( MyObject a, MyObject b)
{
    return !(a == b);
}
}
```

What I noticed from debugging is that if I add a quick watch (after the `KeyNotFoundException` is thrown) for the expression:

```
dict.ElementAt(0).Key == value;
```

it returns true.  How can this be?

**EDIT 2**
So the problem ended up being because `SortedDictionary` (and `Dictionary` as well) are not thread-safe. There was a background thread that was performing some operations on the dictionary which seem to be triggering a resort of the collection (adding items to the collection would do this).  At the same time, when the dictionary iterated through the values to find my key, the collection was being changed and it was not finding my key even though it was there.

Sorry for all of you who asked for code on this one, I'm currently debugging an application that I inherited and I didn't realize this was going on on a timed, background thread.  As such, I thought I copied and pasted all the relevant code, but I didn't realize there was another thread running behind everything manipulating the collection.

Comment: You need to *override* Equals (and GetHashCode), although you may also  want to overload it too. Please show your class - or rather, a short but complete program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: To be clear: You observed this first without any override/overload of Equals/==/GetHashCode ?  Because a faulty implementation of thos would be the easy answer.

Comment: @JonSkeet - You're right, I mis-typed. I did _override_ the `Equals` (and `GetHashCode`) methods.  I added the relevant code.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Great question!  I saw the problem before overriding the `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods and went down that path when I noticed problems.

Comment: Okay, well that looks okay. Now can you produce a short but complete example demonstrating the problem?

Comment: @JonSkeet - The two lines of code in the beginning of the question are exactly the lines I'm using in my code.

Comment: @JoelB: But they're not a short but complete program, are they? I'm talking about a complete program (ideally a console app) I can copy, paste, compile, run, and see the issue you're seeing.

Comment: An app is desired because the issue is unresolved. Equality based on a mutable property is simply a bad idea but you state the problem appeared w/o any overrides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the problem ended up being because `SortedDictionary` is not thread-safe. There was a background thread that was performing some operations on the dictionary (adding items to the collection) which seems to be triggering a resort of the collection. At the same time, when the dictionary was attempting to iterate through the values to find my key, the collection was being changed and resorted, rendering the enumerator invalid, and it was not finding my key even though it was there.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to overloading `==` and `Equals`, make sure you override [`GetHashCode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with a suitable hash function. In particular, see this specification from the documentation:

> - If two objects compare as equal, the `GetHashCode` method for each object must return the same value. However, if two objects do not
>     compare as equal, the `GetHashCode` methods for the two objects do not
>     have to return different values.
> - The `GetHashCode` method for an object must consistently return the same hash code as long as there is no modification to the object state
>     that determines the return value of the object's Equals method. Note
>     that this is true only for the current execution of an application,
>     and that a different hash code can be returned if the application is
>     run again.
> - For the best performance, a hash function should generate an even distribution for all input, including input that is heavily clustered.
>     An implication is that small modifications to object state should
>     result in large modifications to the resulting hash code for best hash
>     table performance.
> - Hash functions should be inexpensive to compute.
> - The `GetHashCode` method should not throw exceptions.

---

I agree with [*Jon Skeet*'s suspicion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18341416/1715579) that you're somehow unintentionally modifying `UserID` property after it's added as a key. But since the only property that's important for testing equality in `MyObject` is `UserID` (and therefore that's the only property that the `Dictionary` cares about), I'd recommend refactoring your code to use a simple `Dictionary<ulong, IMyInterface>` instead:

```
Dictionary<ulong, IMyInterface> dict = new Dictionary<string, IMyInterface>();
ulong userID = dict.Keys.First();
var value = dict[userID];
```

Comment: @JoelB Please show your implementation of `==`, `Equals`, and `GetHashCode`. We may be able to spot the error.

Answer (score 0):

I have a suspicion - it's possible that you're *changing* the `UserID` of the key after insertion. For example, this would demonstrate the problem:

```
var key = new MyObject { UserId = 10 };
var dictionary = new Dictionary<MyObject, string>();
dictionary[key] = "foo";

key.UserId = 20; // This will change the hash code

var value = dict[key]; // Bang!
```

You shouldn't change properties involved in equality/hash-code considerations for an object which is being used as the key in a hash-based collection. Ideally, change your code so that this *can't* be changed - make `UserId` readonly, initialized on construction.

The above definitely *would* cause a problem - but it's possible that it's not the same as the problem you're seeing, of course.

Comment: Point taken and I will definitely include protections against that if I keep my overridden `GetHashCode` implementation.  In this case that isn't the issue since I was experiencing the problem before I overrode `GetHashCode`

Comment: @JoelB: Well had you overridden `Equals` at that point? This is the only explanation I can think of, but as we've currently got no way of reproducing the issue, we're left guessing. Again, if you can provide a way of reproducing this, we're much more likely to be able to help you.